# How do you invoke a method?

Tags: java, for-loop

How would i invoke this method for it to print out when i call it in eclipse ???

```
public class Arraymini {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] testArray1= {1,6,3,9,2};
        double [] testArray2= {2.3, 8.66, 6.5, -9.2};
    }

    public static void printArray(int []k){
        for(int i=0; i<k.length; i++){
        System.out.println(k[i]+" ");
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(double[]g){
        for(int i=0; i<g.length; i++){
            System.out.println(g[i]+" ");
        }
    }

}
```

also is their a way i am suppose to change the foor loop for it to print out in a row  ?????

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: You even didn't call the method.

Comment: noooo duhhh thats what i am asking how to do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Arraymini {

public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] testArray1= {1,6,3,9,2};
    double [] testArray2= {2.3, 8.66, 6.5, -9.2};
    printArray(testArray1);
    printArray(testArray2);
}

public static void printArray(int []k){
    for(int i=0; i<k.length; i++){
    System.out.println(k[i]+" ");
    }
}

public static void printArray(double[]g){
    for(int i=0; i<g.length; i++){
        System.out.println(g[i]+" ");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` method, you can call your methods by using:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //-- Your original code up above

    printArray(testArray1); //For the array of ints
    printArray(testArray2); //For the array of doubles
}
```

Comment: The first method prints an array of ints, the second one prints an array of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int[] testArray1 = {1,6,3,9,2};
    double[] testArray2 = {2.3, 8.66, 6.5, -9.2};
    printArray(testArray1);
    printArray(testArray2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `main()` function:

```
printArray(testArray1);
printArray(testArray2);
```